# viewWillTransition not being called swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to detect orientation changes on my iOS device. I thought it would be simple to do but in practice it's not working...

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    print("Will Transition to size \(size) from super view size \(self.view.frame.size)")

    if (size.width > self.view.frame.size.width) {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }

    if (size.width != self.view.frame.size.width) {
        // Reload TableView to update cell's constraints.
        // Ensuring no dequeued cells have old constraints.

    }


}
```

The above is the code I found here on stackoverflow. viewWillTransition is not being called. I notice posts insist on putting a super for it to work, but no, as you can see there is a super and its still not working.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

Was my next attempt at fixing it, did nothing.

Help?

Comment: Probably your view controller is inside a container view controller (maybe a UINavigationController?) that isn’t passing the events to its children.

Comment: Ah ok. How cn I pass events to a child from UINavigationController? That is most definately the issue!

Comment: Can you update your question with info about your view hierarchy? What are the view controllers between this one and your app's root view controller? How are you creating them (code/storyboard)? Etc.

Comment: Adding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has nothing to do with your use of `viewWillTransition`. You should call `super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with coordinator)` in your own `viewWillTransition` but that has no effect on whether yours is called or not. It should be called. You need to update this question with details about how your view controllers are setup and created.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom container view?
If you have added a child viewController's view to a parent viewController as a subview you must call the `.addChild(_:)` method on the parent viewController to create the parent-child relationship between the two view controllers.

Answer (score -4):

I think this would help:--

if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft{

print("Anything")

}
else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight{

print("Anything")

}
else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown{

print("Anything")

}
else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.UIDeviceOrientationPortrait{

print("Anything")

}

Comment: Why not just one statement of `print("Current orientation: " + UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)`?